# Updating Table2 when data found in table1

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

Forgive me if I make a fool of myself but still fairly new to mysql queries beyond the "basic" kind. Currently I have two tables of data.

Table 1 has data parsed into it using a LOAD INTO and Table 2 has data manually entered for user information. This is pulled automatically from a | delimited file twice a day.

The following are columns are in Table1 that have the data I need to verify against (there are more columns than just these):

```
sendID |  recID | transAmt | transDate | transStatus
```

And the following columns are from Table2:

```
userID | userName | currentCapacity | maxCapacity
```

What I'm trying to do is run an update where the `userID` `curentCapacity` is increased by one, when the `userID` is found in `sendID` or `recID` but only when the `transStatus = Active`. I've tried the following:

```
UPDATE table1,table2
SET table2.currentCapacity=table2.currentCapacity+1 
WHERE ( table2.transStatus="Active" AND (table2.userID = table1.sendID OR table1.recID))
```

This works and the `currentCapacity` is increased by 1, but it is ONLY increased by one. The effect I'm going for is to set the `currentCapacity` to equal the sum of all `transStatus`="Active".

I tried the following and it returns "#1111 - Invalid use of group function" error:

```
UPDATE table1,table2
SET table2.currentCapacity=SUM(table1.transStatus) 
WHERE ( table2.transStatus="Active" AND (table2.userID = table1.sendID OR table1.recID))
```

Any suggestions or guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try if it gives your desired result, (***not manually tested***)

```
UPDATE  table2 b
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID, SUM(transStatus = 'Active') total
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  sendID ID, transStatus FROM table1
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  recID ID, transStatus FROM table1
                    ) x
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) a ON b.userID = a.ID
SET     b.currentCapacity = a.total
```

Comment: I made the assumption that the second SELECT you included in the FROM was supposed to be table1 as well and changed it, ran the query and it works! Thanks so much!